# What are some safer alternatives to metal wire grill brushes?

Tags: grilling, barbecue, grill

There are [some dangers](https://www.goodhousekeeping.com/food-recipes/a32733/wire-grill-brush-dangers/) in using wire grill brushes.

How can a grill be safely cleaned without the risk of wires getting into food?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a cloth, a ball of aluminum foil, or a wooden scraper....or, just use a grill brush and wipe with a cloth after brushing to ensure there is no debris, either from the grill or the brush, left on the grill.

Comment: Wiping doesn’t always work.  I’ve noticed them stuck to the side of the grate, so food that dipped down come in contact and adhered when cooking.  (I think it was deboned chicken)

Comment: Also, other cleaning items: the metal blade side of a a grill brush (if it has one), large bricks of pumice stone, grill brushes that are made from coils of wire.  You might also be able use a wok brush before it’s heated (strips of cut bamboo bound together)

Comment: If you are worried about bits of metal in the food I wouldn't use a ball of aluminium foil. Aluminium foil is much more fragile than any metal brush and the risks of small chunks tearing off is much higher than with a wire sponge.

Answer (score 2):

The grilling industry would be trilled to sell you any number of alternate cleaning devices.  These come in three main types.

First, there's the non-wire brushes.  The best of these, and what I use, are [nylon with abrasive grit](https://www.charbroil.com/safer-replaceable-head-grill-brush-8666894).  In addition to being non-wire, they're also great for use with more delicate grill types, like my cast aluminum grates.  They need to be used while the grill is cold.

Second, you can get [grill "scrubbies"](https://www.acehardware.com/departments/outdoor-living/grills-and-smokers/grilling-utensils-and-tools/8014052?store=17402), which basically attach a heavy-duty kitchen scrubber to a handle.  While [some of these are wire or metal](https://www.biglots.com/product/steel-mesh-grill-scrubber/p810327502), since it's in loops it doesn't carry the same dangers as regular wire brushes.  These are great for getting off really baked-on messes, but aren't so good for getting between the grate slats.

The third type are scrapers.  The most dramatic of these are [the wooden scrapers](https://www.greatscrape.com/) which you first use on a very hot grill to burn the shape of your grill grate into them.  I don't know how well these actually work, but they look cool.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I saw in your edit summary that you said that site has malware. What malware does it have? There's definitely controversial content on the site, but not on that page as far as I could tell, and even on the political pages I've never seen malware.

Comment: I got an alert from privacy badger on several of the ads.  Since that story is available from multiple outlets, I just swapped in a different one.